# How to I take the quotient $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I am using the following representation of the $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ group.

$$
\exp( a+x \sigma_1 +y \sigma_2 + b \sigma_1\sigma_2) = \exp( \begin{bmatrix}a+x & -b +y  \\  b+y & a-x\end{bmatrix})
$$

If I pose $a \to 0, x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$, then I have effectively reduced the group from $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ to $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$.

$$
\exp (b\sigma_1\sigma_2) = \exp( \begin{bmatrix}0 & -b   \\  b & 0\end{bmatrix})
$$

What is the precise expression for $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R})$? If yes, what is it?

---

edit:

Can I find $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ in the following way:

$$
GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R}) = \exp( a+x \sigma_1 +y \sigma_2 +  b \sigma_1\sigma_2)/\exp (  b \sigma_1\sigma_2)
$$

The next step would be to factor our $ b\sigma_1\sigma_2$ from $\exp(a+ x \sigma_1 +y \sigma_2 +  b\sigma_1\sigma_2)$?

But since $[x \sigma_1 +y \sigma_2,  b\sigma_1\sigma_2]\neq 0$, I have to use this formula?

[image]

I end up with

$$
GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R}) = \exp (a) \exp(x \sigma_1 +y \sigma_2)\exp( \frac{-1}{2}[ x\sigma_1 +y \sigma_2,  b\sigma_1\sigma_2]) \exp (...)
$$

I was previously told $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ yields the group of all Riemmanian metrics in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I do not see where the metrics are in my result.

Comment: Why do you switch from $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ to $GL(4,\mathbb R)$? Are all supposed to be $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ instead?

Comment: @student91 typo, sorry and edited. Should all be $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Note that in $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R})$, the "$/$" is a way to denote a quotient group. You can find more on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) or [an introductory video on youtube](https://youtu.be/N11vOq3h9XQ). esp. Wikipedia has a section "Motivation for the name" that explains this is not exactly division.

Comment: @student91 Thank you for the reference. I have rephrased the question to : is there a precise expression for $GL^+(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R})$. If yes, what is it?

Comment: One of the most basic examples of a homogeneous space is $SO(3,\Bbb R)/SO(2,\Bbb R)$. Can you see why this is (diffeomorphic to) a $2$-dimensional sphere? (Go read about group actions on sets and the important orbit-stabilizer theorem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a quotient group but a homogeneous space, i.e. you take elements of $GL^+(2,\mathbb R)$ and identify $A$ and $B$ if and only if $B=AC$ for some $C\in SO(2)$. In general, there is no canonical way to realize a homogeneous space of a matrix group as a subset of $\mathbb R^N$ for any $N$. (This is one of the reasons why one looks at abstract manifolds.) However for this example, there is a nice explicit way to explicitly understand it: You can send a matrix $A\in GL^+(4,\mathbb R)$ and map it to $AA^t$, which is a symmetric, positive definite $2\times 2$-matrix. Now if $B=AC$ for $C\in SO(2)$, then $B^t=C^tB^t$, so $BB^t=AA^t$. One verifies that this indeed gives rise to a diffeomorphism from $GL^+(2,\mathbb R)/SO(2)$ to the space of positive definite, symmetric $2\times 2$-matrices.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you also take look at my edit, please? I am wondering, if this is an alternative way to find this answer? Or why it fails if its not.

Comment: It is not the (infinite-dimensional) space of Riemannian metrics on $\mathbb R^n$ but the (finite-dimensional) space of inner products on $\mathbb R^n$ and you can see this in my answer. The reason why your suggestion won't really work is because the exponential map of $GL^+(2,\mathbb R)$ is not surjective. And you cannot simply divide in a non-commutative group, so it is not clear what you mean there.

Comment: But since C is invertible, shouldn't I be able to take $(B)C^{-1}=(AC)C^{-1}$, thus dividing $B \in GL^+$ with $C \in SO$?

Comment: Yes, you can (you just have to specify whether you mean $BC^{-1}$ or $C^{-1}B$. I guess the problem is that you are mis-interpreting the meaning of "$/$" in $G/H$. It does not mean division but $G/H$ denotes the set of equivalence classes of the equivalence relation on $G$ defined by $q_1\sim q_2$ if and only if there is an $h\in H$ such that $g_2=g_1h$. So to describe $G/H$ you need to describe this set of equivalence classes and not divide elements of $G$ by elements of $H$.

Comment: It seems there are no general widely-used algorithms (like division) to describe such quotient G/H. All I read are a bullet point list of arguments stating the reasoning behind some G/H construction. Are such constructions done by inspection as case by case basis?

Comment: So, essentially, the group elements missing from the exponential map  $\exp gl(2,R)$ (not surjective with $GL(2,R)$) prevent the division by $SO(2)$?

Comment: It is a general Theorem that the set of left cosets (i.e. the equivalence classes of the relation that I described) in a Lie group with respect to a closed subgroup can be canonically made into a manifold. An explicit approach to describing this space of cosets does (at least as fat as I can see) not amount to "division" in any sense but to finding a uniform constructions for representattives in the cosets. But it is clear that in general this can only work locally.